# Perl - Detect header record

Tags: regex, perl, header, detect

If I have a text file that has a header record and field delimited by a pipe "|" something like -->

```
Column1|Column2|Column3\n
A|B|C\n
E|F|G\n
1|2|X\n
```

Is there a way I can determine if the header record exists in the file programmatically? The catch is that the headers aren't always consistent (so, Column1 may be called Column100 in some files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way i know: header row fields are almost certainly words (text), data rows are in different data types (by columns). So, if there are columns by types but not same type in first row, the header is present.

You need some kind of data-type tester and about 5 rows from this text file to get it clear.

Comment: Good enough for a start! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could read the first line of the file, split it on "|", and check to make sure that each column name matches the regex `/^Column\d+$/`.

```
my @columns = split /\|/, $first_line;
if ( @columns == grep { m/^Column\d+$/ } @columns ) {
    # each column in the first line looks like a header
} else {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, the example I gave is a bad one. The headers are more like: Column1|Field2|ABC3|XYZ4

Comment: @Chris: There must be some way to distinguish the header from the data, otherwise it is impossible to do this. Even in your simple first case, the solution would not work if the first data-line only had columns like "Column1".

Comment: Can you clarify how the column names differ from any data that might appear in the file? If there is no distinct difference between what could be a column name and what could be data you will not be able to spot if there is a line containing header names.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't give enough info. The only distince property of the header that you describe is the pipe symbol, and that can't exist in anything other than the header, which can't be preceded by a non-pipe line.